# Ruby on Rails 3.1 TypeError: 'word' is undefined in .js.coffee file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I wrote some JQuery code in an .js.coffee file and I get the following error: TypeError: 'word' is undefined.

I am new with Rails 3.1 so I am not sure what this error message means.

Here is a snippet of the code int the .js.coffee file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#project_name").focus(function(){
    changeBorder("project_name");
});
$("#project_name").blur(function(){
    resetBorder("project_name");
});
...
});

 function changeBorder(formName){
$("#" + formName).css({border: '1px solid #168DD8', background: '#f2f2f2'});
 }

 function resetBorder(formName){
$("#" + formName).css({border: '1px solid #999999', background: '#ffffff'});
 }
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: why are you writing javascript in your .js.coffee file? If you want to use Javascript, rename it file extension to .js

Comment: Yeah, I was just utilizing what rails generated. I just read over some of the coffeescript documentation and its a lot different syntax wise. I will just simply make it a .js file. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you writing javascript in your .js.coffee file? If you want to use Javascript, rename file extension to .js